# How to retrieve a scalar form a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to retrieve a single scalar from a pandas dataframe column using filtering on another. I am using `.value[0]` but I would like something better.

```
df['Age_in_years'][ df['Sample_id'] == id_sample ].values[0]
df.loc[df['Sample_id'] == id_sample, 'Age_in_years'].values[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `idxmax()` on the condition series, which returns:

> Index of first occurrence of maximum of values.

Which in this case is the *Index of the first True*, and then use `loc` to find the corresponding value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'value': [2,2,2,3,3,3]})

df
#  id   value
#0  1   2
#1  2   2
#2  3   2
#3  4   3
#4  5   3
#5  6   3

df.loc[(df.value == 3).idxmax(), 'id']
# 4
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here are a few different ways to achieve the same result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'value': [2,2,2,3,3,3]})

df.loc[(df.value == 3).nonzero()[0][0], 'id']

df.loc[np.where(df.value == 3)[0][0], 'id']

df.loc[df.value.where(df.value == 3).first_valid_index(), 'id']

df.loc[next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(df.value) if val==3), 'id']
```

The last, although the longest in terms of characters, will be fast for large arrays if the value being searched is near the start of the series.